# Does Jdbi3 guarantee rollback on transaction for every type of Exception?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi, jdbi3

I have a code like this one:

```
jdbi.inTransaction(h -> {
            
            Dao1 dao1 = h.attach(Dao1.class);
            
            if(!dao1.somequery()) {
                
                throw new CustomException("foobar");
            }

            // ... other statements
}
```

Can I be sure that if `CustomException` is thrown `jdbi` will rollback the transaction or this happen only with `SQLException` or Jdbi related Exceptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider Jdbi 3.27.0.

## Documentation

Please, see [the Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jdbi/jdbi3-core/3.27.0/org/jdbi/v3/core/Jdbi.html#inTransaction(org.jdbi.v3.core.HandleCallback)) for the `org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi#inTransaction(org.jdbi.v3.core.HandleCallback<R,X>)` method:

> #### inTransaction
>
> public <R, X extends [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)> R inTransaction ([HandleCallback](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jdbi/jdbi3-core/3.27.0/org/jdbi/v3/core/HandleCallback.html)<R,X> callback) throws X
>
> A convenience function which manages the lifecycle of a handle and yields it to a callback for use by clients. The handle will be in a transaction when the callback is invoked, and that transaction will be committed if the callback finishes normally, or rolled back if the callback raises an exception.
>
> Type Parameters:
>
> `R` - type returned by the callback
>
> `X` - exception type thrown by the callback, if any.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `callback` - A callback which will receive an open Handle, in a transaction
>
> Returns:
>
> the value returned by callback
>
> Throws:
>
> `X` - any exception thrown by the callback

Please, note the text marked in bold, which should answer your question:

> The handle will be in a transaction when the callback is invoked, and that transaction will be committed if the callback finishes normally, or **rolled back if the callback raises an exception**.

> Throws:
>
> `X` - **any exception thrown by the callback**

As we can see, there is **no statement** claiming that the exception handling behavior depends on the exception type.

## Source code

Please, consider the information provided in this section as a draft: it may be rough (imprecise).

There are tests that cover the transaction-related functionality.
The tests are represented by the `TestTransactions` class: [jdbi/TestTransactions.java at v3.27.0 · jdbi/jdbi](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.27.0/core/src/test/java/org/jdbi/v3/core/transaction/TestTransactions.java).

Please, take a look at the entire test class.

Then, please, note the following exception-related test methods:

1. `testExceptionAbortsTransaction()`.
2. `testExceptionAbortsUseTransaction()`.

As we can examine from the implementations of **these test methods**:

1. The implementations use the `java.io.IOException` exception type.
2. The implementations **does not mention** that the exception handling behavior depends on the exception type.